# National visa D for training - Basel, Switzerland

Tags: indian-citizens, switzerland

I am from India and I have been offered postdoc in University of Basel, Switzerland for three years. The University HR has asked to check the Swiss Embassy homepage to apply for visa D for training. In the embassy page (https://www.eda.admin.ch/countries/india/en/home/visa/entry-ch/work-permits/documents-work-permits.html), I have been asked to fill a visa application and give 2 passport photos, authorization letter, passport. No flight tickets have to be booked to apply for visa D?. How is the visa application processed here in India for Visa D?

Thanks

Priya

Comment: Ask the University HR or Foreign Students' Office what the procedure is. They'll have faced these issues many times.

Comment: With a tourist visa, they want to be convinced that you have plans to leave again. A return ticket shows your itinerary. With a long-term visa, they realize that you don't know for sure when you will leave, and tickets to *come* are not the issue.